# Where can one get the coco utils modules? (unable to find them in hf datasets)

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, huggingface-datasets

I have been following [this tutorial](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/DETR/Fine_tuning_DetrForObjectDetection_on_custom_dataset_(balloon).ipynb) which is a walk-through of fine-tuning a pre-trained Detr model

While trying to evaluate the model, I should be using `from datasets import get_coco_api_from_dataset`.  However, I am getting an `ImportError` while doing that:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'get_coco_api_from_dataset'`

I don't seem to find the `coco_eval` module too. So, this line fails: `from datasets.coco_eval import CocoEvaluator`.  Were the coco-related modules shifted somewhere, or do I need to import them from a different package?

Can someone please help me understand how can I import this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems it gets cloned in the step before in that notebook. See https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr/tree/main/datasets.